# Is it possible to exclude some tags from the profile preview?

Tags: support

I have written to my profile something using `[tag:foo]` syntax.

It seems like the preview of my profile uses the first 3 ones. Appart from `CSS` I have nothing todo anymore with these tags. I just used them to show where I am coming from.

[image: Tags]

Is it possible to exclude them and user later tags (I use at the end of the document)? Or use my interested tags like [documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56065/add-tags-to-the-user-profile)?

Comment: It is just picking up links from your about me page. If you want other links to appear there move those 3 to the end, while moving the ones you rather see closer to the top.of your about me.